# Merge internal repository into external repository without showing all commits

Tags: git, merge

I've got `internal` and `external` repositories. `external` lags behind `internal` and is *mostly* a mirror (sometimes there needs to be minor differences between the two). `main` is the primary branch in each repository (historically called `master`)

What I'm trying to do is the following flow:

```
A - B - C - D - E  (internal branch: main)
        \       \  
 -   -   C   -   E  (internal branch: tracking)

tracking pushes to external branch: to-merge, then to-merge gets merged with external main, resulting in:

 -   -   C   -   E  (external branch: main)
```

When setting this up initially, I `git checkout -b`ed at `C` a branch from `internal` called `tracking` with `external` as a remote. I squashed (using `git rebase -i HEAD~X` flow) so that `C` was the only commit showing up (although if I understand correctly...this creates a new commit? So is it actually `C'` i.e. something totally new?), then pushed that branch to a remote branch `to-merge` in `external` (this is how I'm transferring files from one repo to the other)

After `internal` `main` goes to commit `E`, I cannot do a fast-forward merge from C on the branch `tracking` (maybe because `C` on `tracking` is `C'`??) so I have to resolve all the merge conflicts manually, which is what I'm trying to avoid.

Is there an easier way to do this? The easiest way I can think of is to copy all the files at each milestone commit on `internal main` that I want to transfer to `external main`, and just create new commits, but that doesn't seem very `git`-esque. Suggestions?

To preempt some questions: no, I cannot allow intermediate commits to show up in the external repository.

Comment: To get E onto tracking after C, cherry pick it.

Comment: What you're doing as a whole is not very Git-esque: Git is about commits and commits *are* the history and you want to have a different history, so you need different commits, so you need a separate repository and the two repositories should never meet. (That's not a hard and fast rule, it's just a way to make sure you never accidentally "pollute" the external repository with the internal commits.)

Comment: Given that the repositories don't meet up, it's impossible to merge one to the other. You can weaken the "no meeting up" rule (at some risk) but that turns out not to help anyway, so there's no point in weakening the rule.